# Как добавить box collider через код

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создаю копию объекта через Instantiate (у оригинала стоит Box-Collider) в итоге у копии компонент такой есть, но галочка почему-то снята. Как галочку поставить с помощью кода?

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, какую именно галочку? Активность? IsTrigger? Или что-то другое?

Comment: Конкретно возле Box-Collider

Comment: Видимо, все же речь идет об активности самого компонента. Не знаю, сработает ли это с физическими компонентами, но с другими обычными работает изменение параметра enabled = true;

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский, все компоненты так работают, в том числе и физические

Comment: галочки по прежнему нет

Comment: Приведите свой код.

Answer (score 0):

чтобы добавить любой компонент используйте:

```
(объект которому нужно что то добавить).AddComponent<название компонента>();
```

можете сохранить ссылку на этот компонент и уже менять его параметры.

Answer (score 0):

Object.GetComponent().enable = true;